# Why assigning to property resulting error "cannot set property of null"

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to assign some value to some property of object. But the console logged error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'requested_date' of null`. I have tried to find what is wrong but I think it's all fine.

Here is the code:

```
form = {
    data: null as IMediaStorageAdd,
    requester: null as string
}
```

The IMediaStorageAdd is an interface:

```
export interface IMediaStorageAdd {
    place: string;
    requested_date: any;
    temp_requested_date: any;
    details: any[];
}
```

and this is where i run the assignemnt:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form.requester = localStorage.getItem(`name`);
    this.form.data.requested_date = new Date();
    /* resulting error Cannot set property 'requested_date' of null */
}
```

Comment: @Hiteshdua1 get Item form local Stoage is working fine. Even though I comment the line, I still getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before setting the requested date, you need assign an empty object to data property of the form. Otherwise data is null and hence it is throwing the error. To fix it,

add a line before setting the requested_date as,

```
this.form.data = {};
```

Comment: Form already has both the properties.
``` form = {
    data: null as IMediaStorageAdd,
    requester: null as string
}```

Comment: He is suggesting to set it as `{}` instead of null. Then only you can add properties to it.

Comment: My bad, I am dumb ! :/ yes seems legit.

Comment: Actually, i don't understand why it should assigned by empty object first, because i have set the this.form.data with an interfae. But it's working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983215/1032370) is correct and it's working. I will try to shed some lights to clarify your doubts.

You are setting this.form.data to null and typecasting it using an interface, but still this.form.data is null and not an object.

I believe you can compile TS with --strictNullChecks to avoid this confusion in order to avoid assigning null or undefined to anything.

Anyway, in your case, I think either you initialise your form using same types as you expect:

```
form = {
    data: {} as IMediaStorageAdd,
    requester: '' as string
}
```

or you need to initialise your form data before use it:

1) If there's a class implemeting your IMediaStorageAdd interface

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form.requester = localStorage.getItem(`name`);
    // where class MediaStorageAdd implements IMediaStorageAdd
    this.form.data = new MediaStorageAdd();
    // this could be done in the class MediaStorageAdd constructor actually
    this.form.data.requested_date = new Date();
}
```

2) If no class is implementing your IMediaStorageAdd interface, then you should define it as a type, first of all and then initialise your form data using an object literal

```
export type TMediaStorageAdd {
    requested_date: any;
    place?: string;
    temp_requested_date?: any;
    details?: any[];
}

form = {
    data: null as TMediaStorageAdd,
    requester: null as string
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.form.requester = localStorage.getItem(`name`);
    this.form.data = {
        requested_date = new Date();
    }
}
```